# how to integrate jade and reactjs components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, pug

What is best approach to integrate [Wekan](https://github.com/wekan/wekan) which is meteorjs app but UI is written using Jade with [coreui template](https://github.com/matiasmagni/coreui-meteor-react/blob/master/README.md) which is meteorjs app but UI is written in ReactJs.

Comment: have you check https://github.com/wekan/wekan/issues/299 this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a babel plugin like "babel-plugin-transform-react-pug", to learn more, [click here](https://github.com/pugjs/babel-plugin-transform-react-pug)